# JS-prototype functionextension with own Collection Name

Tags: javascript, prototype, expand

I want to expand all SVGElement with some new functions.

For example:

```
SVGElement.prototype.logType= function () {
            console.log('I am a SVGelement from type: ' + this.nodeName);
        }
```

If svgText is a svgText-Objekt and i call svgText.logType()
This works fine... -> log is "I am a SVGelement form type: svgText"

But i like to have all my function with a prefix my.
I tryed:

```
SVGElement.my= {};
SVGElement.prototype.my.logType= function () {
    console.log('I am a SVGelement from type: ' + this.nodeName);
}
```

The Problem is, when i call svgText.my.logType(), "this" points to "my"-Objekt, and not the svgText-Object.

Is there a way? Thx for help and sorry for my english ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a "my" prefix on all the additions you make, by far the simplest way is to make it part of the method name instead:

```
SVGElement.prototype.myLogType = function() { /*...*/ };
// ------------------^^
```

But in general, don't use direct assignment to create new methods on objects used as prototypes, it creates an enumerable property, which tends to be problematic. Instead, use `Object.defineProperty` and don't make the new property enumerable (it will be non-enumerable by default).

```
Object.defineProperty(SVGElement.prototype, "myLogType", {
    value: function() { /*...*/ },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

---

However, it's *possible* to do what you want, it's just (slightly) inefficient and cumbersome: Make `my` a property with an accessor function and custom-generate the object you return the first time it's used on an instance.

See comments:

```js
// Stand-in for SVGElement for the example
function FakeElement(id) {
  this.id = id;
}

// An object with the methods we want to add
var ourMethods = {
  logText: function() {
    return this.id;
  }
};

// Add our "my" property
Object.defineProperty(FakeElement.prototype, "my", {
  get() {
    // If we're being called on the prototype object itself, don't
    // do anything and just return null
    if (this === FakeElement.prototype) {
      return null;
    }
    
    // Define 'my' on this specific object with bound functions
    console.log("Creating 'my' for element id = " + this.id);
    var obj = this;
    var my = {};
    Object.keys(ourMethods).forEach(function(key) {
      my[key] = ourMethods[key].bind(obj);
    });
    Object.defineProperty(this, "my", {value: my});
    
    return my;
  }
});

// Test it
var f1 = new FakeElement(1);
var f2 = new FakeElement(2);
console.log(f1.my.logText());
console.log(f2.my.logText());
console.log(f1.my.logText());
console.log(f2.my.logText());
```

That's written for clarity, not brevity, and if we were taking advantage of ES2015+ improvements to JavaScript could be more concise, but hopefully it gets you started...